# Update rows based on rownumber in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, cursor, sql-update

Ive been given some data in a spreadsheet which will soon be going into an automated import so i cannot do any manual entry on the spreadsheet. The data basically has the following columns. Trayid, trayname, itemdescription and rownumber. I didnt build these tables myself or i would of built it differently but i have to stick to the format which is already set.

The Data that is being imported will look at followed.

```
Trayid | Trayname | ItemDescription | RowNumber
1        Tray 1     Product 1         1
                    Product 2         2
                    Product 3         3
                    Product 4         4
2        Tray 2     Product 1         1
                    Product 2         2
                    Product 3         3
                    Product 4         4
                    Product 5         5
```

What i need to do is update the trayid and trayname for each of the other rows following row 1, so for example it will look like.

```
Trayid | Trayname | ItemDescription | RowNumber
1        Tray 1     Product 1         1
1        Tray 1     Product 2         2
1        Tray 1     Product 3         3
1        Tray 1     Product 4         4
2        Tray 2     Product 1         1
2        Tray 2     Product 2         2
2        Tray 2     Product 3         3
2        Tray 2     Product 4         4
2        Tray 2     Product 5         5
```

Im guessing i need to use a curser or something but im not sure, i think it can be done by going down the rownumbers and stopping when it see's rownumber 1 again and then carrying on with the next trayid and trayname.

Sorry if what i need doesnt make sense, it was awkward to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL tables have no inherent ordering.  So you cannot depend on that.  But, there is something that you can do:

- Define an `identity` column in the source table.
- Create a view on the source table that excludes the identity.
- Bulk insert into the view.

This will assign a sequential number to rows in the same order as the original data.  Let's call this `id`.  Then you can do your update by doing:

```
with toupdate (
      select t.*,
             max(TrayId) over (partition by grp) as new_TrayId,
             max(TrayName) over (partition by grp) as new_TrayName
      from (select t.*,
                   count(TrayId) over (order by id) as grp
            from t
           ) t
     )
update toupdate
    set TrayId = new_TrayId,
        TrayName = new_TrayName
    where TrayId is null;
```

The idea is to define groups of rows corresponding to each tray.  The simple idea is to count the number of non-NULL values before any given row -- everything in a group will then have the same `grp` value.  Window functions then spread the actual value through all rows in the group (using `max()`), and these values are used for the update.